# Will javascript be in the HTML5 standard 

Tags: javascript, html5

I'm pretty new to the web development scene, and I just want to be absolutely clear on this because I've read a few conflicting statements.

I was under the impression that "html5" is a particular way of constructing xml to represent data for a webpage and "javascript" is a programming language that runs as client-side code in the browser. But left and right I see APIs for javascript (workers, geolocation, local storage, etc.) being referred to as an "html5 technology". Wikipedia says that html5 doesn't have a standard yet, so I can't look it up to see if it somehow mandates stuff about javascript.

So will APIs for javascript somehow be apart of the html5 standard? Or has it become a common bad practice to label javascript APIs "html5 technology"?

Comment: Just a technicality - HTML5 does not have to be valid XML, e.g. the `<br>` tag (without close), is [perfectly valid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1946426/html-5-is-it-br-br-or-br) in HTML5, but not in XML.

Comment: HTML5 is a really bad name. In the end it is more about standardizing common existing stuff from web browsers that were not in a standard yet. This ranges from the parsing algorithm for malformed HTML to Javascript APIs to things like video and so on.

Comment: The official HTML 5 specification (or 'recommendation') was published by the W3C on 28 October 2014 - Web APIs and scripting are covered in Chapter 6: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#webappapis

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not a standard yet, but you can read the draft specification on the [W3 web site](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/webappapis.html#javascript-protocol). Javascript/Ecmascript is part of section 6.1.6: Events.

Comment: Javascript is also explicitely mentioned in 6.1.6, "Events", thus making it an integral part of HTML5.

Comment: @ammoQ thanks for the correction. I've updated my answer.